# query to fetch tables after a certain timestamp not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I am trying to calculate the total earnings after a certain timestamp.
What I want to do:
I have a button which on click adds the total earnings till that time to the table with a timestamp.
As soon as it gets added to the database, from there on i want to display the total earnings earned after that timestamp.
So, that means if there are no earnings after the click of the button, it should show me 0.

Problems:
The thing works only the first time if the database is empty.  Otherwise Values are correctly inserted in the database but the jquery doesnt update the span tags each time I hit the button.

HTML:

```
           <span id="wb_uid8">Earned: </span><span id="wb_uid9">Fetching data..</span>
       <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="Button1" value="I received my incentive today!">

           <span id="wb_uid10"><strong>Last payment receive date:</strong></span><span id="wb_uid11"> </span><span id="wb_uid12"></span><span id="wb_uid13"><br>
           </span><span id="wb_uid14"><strong>Received amount:</strong></span><span id="wb_uid15"> </span><span id="wb_uid16"></span>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#Button1').click(function(){
    var fullDate = new Date();
    var twoDigitMonth = fullDate.getMonth()+"";
     if(twoDigitMonth.length==1){
        twoDigitMonth="0" +twoDigitMonth;
    }
    var twoDigitDate = fullDate.getDate()+"";
    if(twoDigitDate.length==1){
       twoDigitDate="0" +twoDigitDate;
    }
    var currentdate = twoDigitDate+"/"+twoDigitMonth+"/"+fullDate.getFullYear();

    var dataString = 'date='+currentdate;
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        data: dataString,
        url: "receipts.php",
        cache:false
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'checkearnings.php',
        success: function(data){
            var data=JSON.parse(data);
            $('#wb_uid9').html('&#8377; '+ data['earned']);
            $('#wb_uid12').text(data['lastdate']);
            $('#wb_uid16').html('&#8377; '+ data['lastamt']);
        }
    });
}, 1000);
});
</script>
```

checkearnings.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
$earned = 0;
$lastdate = "";
$lastamt = "";
$timestamp = "";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM receipts ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1";
$result1 = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
if($details = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)){
    $lastdate = $details['date'];
    $lastamt = $details['amt'];
    $timestamp = $details['timestamp'];
}
else{
    $lastdate = "Never";
    $lastamt = "Nothing";
}


$sql = "SELECT amt FROM sales WHERE timestamp>'$timestamp'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($fetch_options=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $earned = $earned + $fetch_options['amt'];
}

$responses=array('earned'=>$earned, 'lastdate'=>$lastdate, 'lastamt'=>$lastamt);
$return=$responses;
//echo $earned;
echo json_encode($return);
?>
```

receipts.php

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
include 'checkearnings.php';
if (isset($_POST['date']))
{
    $newdate = $_POST['date'];
    $time = round(microtime(true)*1000);
    $sql = "INSERT `receipts` (`date`, `amt`, `timestamp`) VALUES ('$newdate', '$earned', '$time')";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        mysqli_close($db);
}
?>
```

Comment: You say it works the first time with an empty table, how does it behave otherwise? Is nothing added? Is the wrong row retrieved from the initial `SELECT`? Is an incorrect value added? We need more specifics to be able to assist. It looks like you are constructing a date string as `dd/mm/yyyy` format. MySQL is expecting 'YYYY-MM-DD' and may be casting your initial date to a zero value like `0000-00-00`.

Comment: Otherwise Values are correctly inserted in the database but the jquery doesnt update the span tags each time I hit the button.

Comment: Let me explain, when the table is database is empty I first add some products which I sold. Then when I hit the button my earnings turn to 0. After that I again added some more products which I sold and it perfectly got calculated after the point I hit the button. But now when I hit the button again my earnings do not turn to 0 as if mysql couldn't understand whether the currently added product's timestamp was greater than the last hit button time.

Comment: But did you actually inspect the values in the MySQL table? Your use of `dd/mm/yyyy` for the timestamp is highly suspect. MySQL will accept that value, but will probably not store it as intended.

Comment: I am using microtime function. At first I used NOW () but the same thing occured. Can you show me what I need to do??

Comment: The concerning value isn't the one from `microtime()`, but rather the one in `$_POST['date']` made by `currentdate` in the JS code. The correct format would be `fullDate.getFullYear() + "-" + twoDigitMonth + "-" + twoDigitDate` as `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: But I am not making a query based on that field.

Comment: Yes, your first SELECT on receipts orders on date to limit one record.

Comment: Ok. What if I make the select on timestamp?

Comment: Okay.  :) it worked. Thank you. But the date function in JS  not showing the correct month.